# Any way to create a mail to a lot of users with JS?

Tags: javascript, email

I have to display on the screen a mail, and populate it with a long list of users. (+30-50).

I tried with `window.open(mailto)` & `href.location=mailto`, but I think the URL its too long, and sometimes the mail doesn't appear. With <20 users always works, for example.

So I want to know if there is another way to generate a mail, with JS, that can populate the mail to a lot of users.

Comment: I assume you mean *browser-based* JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, only client-side JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I test the problem.

You can't add to mailto more than 2000 characters, because its like an URL. You have to limit the content.

In OutLook, I solve my problem removing the "Name" that stay with the email, so I reduce the number of characters

Comment: with more than 2k characters the email doesn't pop up

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's another way to open an email window from HTML or JavaScript running on a browser than the `mailto` pseudo-scheme. If what you're doing works with a smaller number of recipients but not a greater number, then I think the answer is "no, you can't do that."